# Maven Include dependencies in Executable Jar

Tags: maven, maven-2, jar-signing

Am new to `Maven`...

Trying to create a simple `applet`.

1. Include dependencies for the `applet`. 
   For this I have tried :

   ```
    <repository>
    <id>lib</id>
    <name>lib</name>
    <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
     <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
   ```

   I have these files included in the `lib` folder under my project structure.
   this lib contains couple of `jar` files and a `JNI dll` which I need to use in my `applet`.
   Is there any better option to create `repository` than the above,Kindly share?
2. Packaging applet `jar` with dependencies.
   For this I have tried :

   ```
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>      
   <executions>
   <execution>
   <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
   <phase>package</phase>
   <goals>
     <goal>single</goal>
   </goals>       
   <configuration>                 
   <descriptorRefs>
     <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
   </descriptorRefs>
   </configuration>
   ```

I expect the above to wrap my dependencies into one single `jar`, but its not been the case.
the generated `jar` file size doesnt contain the dependency `jar` files.(I can say coz the **size** of the `jar` file remains unchanged for both `jars` with and without dependencies are same)

Am I in the right way of doing things with `Maven`?

Answer (score 0):

Take look at [shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), this plugin creates executable "uber jar" or if you realy need something really complicated [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Comment: Thank you, `shade` as well as `maven` are very new to me, I spent some time on trying to learn `maven` because I found it is useful for my applications when it comes to build..so Kindly check the above on what I have tried and advice me If some thing needs to be changed..Once again thanks for your time.